Major AWS Amplify dependency is no longer available? aws-amplify/utils
There are so many examples out there of AWS Cognito setup where they are giving you amplify code to tie in authentication for your app.  But guess what?  One of the dependancies is not longer in existence?
this:
https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react/build-a-backend/utilities/hub/
mentions:

import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify/utils';

but I am getting:
 % npm i aws-amplify/utils 
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/aws-amplify/utils.git
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!!!  Thank you . . .

just use this
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify';

I am currently using Hub in my AWS/React application and it works just fine. I imagine you just need to install aws-amplify via 'npm i aws-amplify' without the "/utils". Then, you can you use the same import statement as you are.
import { Hub } from "aws-amplify/utils";
